# How to connect Phoenix by C#

Tags: c#, apache-phoenix

In python, I could connect Phoenix query service by phoenixdb as below,

`conn = phoenixdb.connect('http://address:8765/', autocommit=True)`

Is there a similar way in c#?

Since I dont know the HBase cluster name, username and password, I cannot use [PhoenixClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hbase/apache-hbase-using-phoenix-query-server-rest-sdk).

Comment: if you don't know the credentials, how did you connect to it with python? Presumably it requires credentials still. Does the python version keep them somewhere else, rather than providing them in the connection method directly? (Or, if in fact no credentials are required for your instance, have you tried simply leaving the username and password null in the C# version?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found I could use PhoenixClient by VNet mode. Then it could connect http://address:8765